# How to make MSBuild MakeDir task work in Azure Pipeline YAML template?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

csproj file with post build event:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
        <MakeDir Directories=".../../artifacts/swagger/v1" Condition="!Exists('../../artifacts/swagger/v1')" />
        <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output ../../artifacts/swagger/v1/swagger.json &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; v1" />
</Target>
```

These steps have worked great locally and in Azure DevOps on both Windows and Linux hosts for a while. But now, I'm trying to change my azure-pipeline.yml to use a custom YAML template. The dotnet build step in the YAML template is fairly straight-forward:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: ${{ parameters.projectsToBuild }}
        arguments: --no-restore --configuration ${{ parameters.configuration }} /p:Version=$(GitVersion.FullSemVer) /p:ContinuousIntegrationBuild=true
```

But, for some reason, now that I have this step in a template, the MakeDir MSBuild task seems to have stopped working because the following step to generate the swagger.json file fails with the following error

```
  Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/artifacts/swagger/v1/swagger.json'.
     at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
     at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
     at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
     at System.IO.StreamWriter.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
     at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
     at System.IO.File.CreateText(String path)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_3(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 90
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 59
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 111
```

How can I get this task to work in a YAML template? Or is there a work around that is as simple and multi-platform?

Answer (score 0):

*After more research I tried:

```xml
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
    <Exec Command="mkdir ..\..\artifacts\swagger\v1" Condition="!Exists('..\..\artifacts\swagger\v1') AND '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'" />
    <Exec Command="mkdir -p ../../artifacts/swagger/v1" Condition="!Exists('../../artifacts/swagger/v1') AND '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output ../../artifacts/swagger/v1/swagger.json &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; v1" />
</Target>
```

This worked but I wanted to use the MakeDir task which is simpler.

I then added a <Message Text="Hello" /> task and turned on diagnostic verbosity and noticed that both the Message task and the MakeDir task were being invoked after the Exec tasks. So, the tasks were succeeding but not running in the right order.

I have no idea why putting the dotnet build task inside of YAML template would consistently cause the Exec MSBuild tasks to run before the other MSBuild tasks but when the dotnet build task is directly inside my azure-pipelines.yml file, the MSBuild tasks consistently run in the correct order.

So, for now, what I have done is **move the MakeDir task to a Pre-Build event** in the csproj. That works consistently.

But if someone can clarify the issue and knows how to get it to work as it is supposed to, I'll accept your answer over mine.